# Removing 1st character of number before checking if its > 0, combined with indirect function

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to use the =indirect() and =value() function together. I am to count how many numbers are > 0 in another sheet, in the rows I:I. In these sheets, **the numbers are not formatted as values**, and I am not to do this manually.
In addition, for the numbers, they are formatted as
" 123 "
With a space before the number.
**I also need to remove the space in front the numbers in order for this to work.**

In my current sheet, in cell J1, I have written "I:I". In the cell A3, I have the name of the sheet that I would like to count the numbers from.
My attempt so far:

```
{=COUNT.IF(INDIRECT("'"&A3&"'!"&$J$1);">0")
```

However, this just returns values 0. This is because there is a space infront of the numbers. How do I remove this space? I need to implement it in this function

I've edited the post a bit, as I noticed there was a space infront of the numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a **worksheet**, if your value `" 123 "` is in cell `A1` then you could use a formula like:

```
=VALUE(TRIM(A1))
```

...to **[`TRIM`](https://support.microsoft.com/office/trim-function-410388fa-c5df-49c6-b16c-9e5630b479f9)** the spaces, and convert the string to a numeric **[`VALUE`](https://support.microsoft.com/office/value-function-257d0108-07dc-437d-ae1c-bc2d3953d8c2)**.

---

Or, in **VBA**, something like:

```
myValue = CInt(Trim(myString))
```

...to **[`Trim`](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/ltrim-rtrim-and-trim-functions)** the spaces, and **C**onvert to **[`CInt`](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/type-conversion-functions)**-eger.

---

Or, in many ad-hoc situations it's easiest to use "[Text to Columns](https://support.microsoft.com/office/split-text-into-different-columns-with-the-convert-text-to-columns-wizard-30b14928-5550-41f5-97ca-7a3e9c363ed7)" to remove padded spaces (or any other character, really).

- More ways to convert text to numbers [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/convert-numbers-stored-as-text-to-numbers-40105f2a-fe79-4477-a171-c5bad0f0a885) and [here](https://helpdeskgeek.com/office-tips/5-ways-to-convert-text-to-numbers-in-excel/).
- More ways to remove unneeded spaces [here](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2013/11/15/trim-spaces-between-words/) and [here](https://www.howtoexcel.org/functions/remove-unwanted-space-characters/).